# Angular 2 DI not working with pipes

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a simple pipe that I want to inject some dependencies, but the Optional and the Host decorators do not work.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'test'
})
export class TestPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(@Optional() @Host() private form: FormGroupDirective) {
    console.log(form); 
  }

  transform(value, args?: any): any {
    return value;
  }

}

<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="text" [formControlName]="'name' | test">
</form>
```

I am getting the error:

> No provider for NgForm!

Comment: Why not? In directive it is working.

Comment: But you can inject services

Comment: Try `Self` instead of Host. Or without it

Comment: Same error. Very wired. If you can inject services why this is not working.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/0GUpkebVKZdT0keHSLOZ?p=preview